# who to resolve the issue )--- Error of the failed to scan error communicating (Samsung scanner )

Tags: samsung, scanning

we issue Ubuntu 12.04 version in desktop and also using Samsung printer 2876nd ,
In the Samsung printer printing , xcopy ,flatted & ADF both are working but facing the Issue of the scanning showing

The error of the failed to scan error communicating.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung has a great install kit;

http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=UNI_HK_EN&CttFileID=6283513&CDCttType=DR&ModelType=N&ModelName=CLX-3305W&VPath=DR/201510/20151027115542328/uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz

Install it and verify that your user belong in the sane group